# What exactly produces gravitational force? It just can't emerge out of no where depending on mass, distance etc

Tags: gravity, earth

I tried getting the answer from the internet but it says that it is still a mystery.

Comment: Who says it can't?

Comment: I consider it to be a "physical property" of mass.

Comment: @javier if it can be then I would love to hear it from you

Comment: Physical properties are the ones that are measurable whose value is taken according to the state of physical system. But here in the case of gravitational force it is measurable but there should be some main base for the existence of it. @David White

Comment: @DavidWhite ok what is mass then? :D

Comment: @Nils, that's the exact question that CERN was trying to answer when they were looking for the Higgs boson.  I'm not up to speed on particle physics or the standard model, but that is where you should look for an answer to your question about mass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to realize that empty space time can be curved (just like empty space can have electromagnetic fields).

Physics allows space to have electromagnetic fields and just tells them how to change based on what electromagnetic fields are nearby.

Similarly, Physics allows spacetime to be curved and just tells the curvature how to changed based on what curvature is nearby.

That's why you can have waves of electromagnetic fields propagating through empty space and why you can have waves of curvature propagate through empty space.

Sometimes the fields can even remain the same, such as the constant field between two charged plates or the curvature outside a star.

Great. Now we have to learn what sources do. What sources do is they allow fields or curvature to change differently than they normally do.

So for instance imagine that space time us curved more outside a massive planet than outside a less massive planet. So you can imagine that just outside the top layer of Jupiter you have spacetime that is curved like outside a Jupiter massed planet. But if you went 100 meters inside the atmosphere, that top 100m layer no longer contributes to the curvature, so spacetime there is curved like that around a less massive planet.

In the empty space outside Jupiter that kind of curvature can connect to itself just fine, but on its own it can't connect to a different kind of curvature. But when there is energy, momentum, pressure, and/or stress then two different kinds of curvature each which normally can only connect to its own type can be sewn together.

Matter can do that because it has energy, momentum, pressure and stress and anything with those things can do that. But the curvature can go through the empty space, matter just allows different types yo be sewn together.

Let's look at an example of how curvature is made.  This time we will look at a star of mass similar to the sun (which has mass $M_\oplus$). Long ago this star was a very very large, very cold ball of hydrogen. And the spacetime outside it was the kind of curvature like that outside a star of mass $M_\oplus.$ But the ball was quite larger and the kind of curvature outside a star of mass $M_\oplus$ is quite small that far out, so there wasn't much curvature.

But the was enough to make the mass fall towards the center. That top most layer as it fell in, left vacuum (empty space) outside it and empty space can make curvature by looking at the curvature around it. When the region formerly occupied by the top layer looks around it sees that outside curvature, the type like around a star of mass $M_\oplus.$ so more of that kind of curvature is produced since that is type that produces itself.  All curvature in a vacuum is of the type that creates itself. Curvature can make curvature.

OK, but the kind of curvature you kind around a star of mass $M_\oplus$ is the kind that natural makes more curvature closer in, so this newly created curvature in this new layer that used to be occupied by the hydrogen gas is of the same type as outside in the vacuum is actually stronger curvature.

So as the star gets smaller and smaller it leaves that natural vacuum type curvature outside as the matter passes through (the matter allows the type of curvature on the inside to match up to the type of curvature outside and allows each layer to line up). And that kind of curvature naturally is more intense the farther in it gets.

So there used to be a big ball of hydrogen gas and not much curvature (since the curvature is weaker inside the gas than the curvature outside would be if it could continue on all the way to the center) and as the gas contracted it allowed the curvature to naturally fill in the newly empty space the way it naturally does. This lead to an actually greater curvature in the newly opened space.

Eventually the gas got so small that the curvature outside it was quite large, at least larger enough to allow a planet our size to go around it at the speed and distance we do.

That is why we feel curvature from the sun, it allowed the focusing type vacuum curvature to propagate all the way into the place where we are, where the gas the sun formed from used to be. The sun left spacetime curved like that as it passed through and we can see that curvature today because it is the kind that can persist and make itself.

So it doesn't emerge from sources, sources leave it behind as they passed through. Huge parts of the galaxy used to be out here, they left the spacetime curved out here as the galaxy contracted and got more stars more concentrated in the middle. Huge amounts of gas used to be out here, they left the solar system curved as they contracted to form the sun. And even the earth used to be made out of parts that were more spread out and as they contracted together they left the region outside it more curved than it used to be because the region outside it was of the type that fills to be stronger.

And curvature in empty space can only evolve the way it naturally can.

Answer (score 2):

The current approach typically says that mass alters the fundamental way that we measure space and time at different points in the universe, which appears as a fictitious "force" if we do not account for it. This becomes a lot less surprising when you find out that particles which *don't* seem to have mass tend to travel at the speed of light, see the rest of the universe as a single point in front of them, and are generally incapable of having internal effects which would help them experience space or time in the first place. In other words, it is *your* mass which allows you to measure space and time in the first place, and so it's not terribly surprising that nearby masses (and other local energy densities) can alter how you measure it.

Comment: Mr. Drost - THAT is an interesting way to look at the universe.  Thanks for a thought provoking comment.

Comment: The mass of an object is a fundamental property of the object; a numerical measure of its inertia; a fundamental measure of the amount of matter in the object so how does this mass allow measure of space and time?

Comment: @SunayanaDevi Well, "fundamental property of the object" is a little extreme; we've known that mass is lost in nuclear decay for example. But in general mass stops you from moving at the speed of light, at which point you cannot experience time and therefore can't experience anything but emission and absorption. Suppose, for instance, that the universe requires everything to be made of massless particles. But maybe two interacting massless particles start orbiting a center of mass, bound together with some interaction energy: the resulting object can move slower than light and experience time.

Comment: @SunayanaDevi - This is all part of General Relativity. You're not going to understand it by getting a few paragraphs on some internet site. Get any 2 textbooks on GR, get to the point where you can solve the equations in them, and if you have any further questions, _then_ start asking around.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I need to read two textbooks for an answer you are not ready to give me?

Comment: Mass is the fundamental property of matter, even the massless particles mass is theoretically taken as zero.

Comment: @SunayanaDevi - If I gave you an honest answer, it would take at least half a textbook to explain it so you could accept it. I'm limited to 500 characters, and others have already written the textbooks.

Comment: @SunayanaDevi, what WhatRoughBeast is probably trying to convey to you (in my opinion) is this: He can spoon feed a fact to you in 2-3 sentences.  Nevertheless, if you are going to understand the underlying key concept(s), you are going to have to do some reading, and a LOT of thinking, which cannot be conveyed in 500 characters.

Comment: @DavidWhite I agree with your opinion

Answer (score 1):

Gravitational force may not need to be continually produced by anything. For example, the Earth is here and it is not produced continually by anything. The same may hold for gravity; it just is there near all the bodies and it is not being produced. Just because we cannot see gravity does not mean it is any less real than the Earth.

Comment: Magnetic force is produces only when a body moves with some velocity in the magnetic field. Personally what I feel is that there should be something like that of magnetic force that the earth and all the other objects in the universe possess that actually causes gravitational force. We can't just assume its presence comparing it with earth.

Comment: Why? You would like to explain gravity based on electromagnetic theory?

Comment: I'm just saying there is a possible explanation for gravitational force just like magnetic force.

Comment: And what is this explanation of the magnetic force that is better than Newton's law of gravity?

Comment: Magnetic force is produced when a charged particle is in motion in the magnetic field produced by movement of electrically charged particles.

Comment: OK, we can offer that. Gravitational force is produced when a massive particle is in motion in the gravitational field produced by the movement (including an effect at 0 movement) of massive particles. Let's call it a day and go home.

Answer (score -3):

I have solved this problem (with the help of Max Planck, Neils Bohr, Albert Einstein, Rutherford, Rydberg, Coulomb, Faraday, and many other). It took many years of research and much study over a period from 1989 to the present. Why did I spend so much effort on this problem? Well I have a very curious nature, and I don't give up easily (plus the fact that I have much education and a great deal of experience in various areas of science.

The simple answer is that gravity is an electromagnetic effect. To begin with, the hydrogen atom consists of but a single electron and a single proton. How could this form of matter be anything but electronic? After some five years of study and investigation, I wrote my first paper and submitted it to the IEEE for publication. However, they could not find anyone to review it. The APS refused to even consider it, so I decided to publish my first book on this subject ("The Secret of Gravity", published in 1997). The force of gravity is basically a dynamic Coulomb force that is dependent upon the motions of the electron and the proton in the hydrogen atom. For those many readers who would doubt this, you should know that Quantum Theory was based on the atom as an electromagnetic system (see "Plancks Columbia Lectures", 1900). He chose the electronic model of the atom for his model.

My first model was not complete, as I had yet to account for the Rydberg frequencies of radiation and the orbit. Bohr presented an abstract model which did correlate to the Rydberg frequencies, but his model had an orbit with unrestricted radius size. After QM began to become accepted, physicists had to abandon the Bohr model, since their measurements showed a huge discrepancy. I proposed such a model in my third book: "Secrets of the Atom". A proper orbital was presented in these books, but the precise model equation had yet to be established. This was completed in my fifth book: "The Birth of an Atom", which showed how an atom was created from electrical charges, and a precise model of the atom was presented.

When you try to find the answer to the question of gravitational force, there are many conflicting answers and much confusion and disagreement. I invite anyone to challenge me on my writings, which include extensive proofs and are in agreement with the works of Planck, Boltzmann, Bohr, Rydberg, Coulomb, Fitzgerald, Heaviside, Joule, Kelvin, Nernst, Maxwell, Cauchy and other great scientists of the past. Note that I may be the only one, other than Einstein, who derived his energy equation, and I did it in two short pages of my third book.

For reference, readers may want to study "Planck's Columbia Lectures", in which case I recommend my book on the subject, which includes detailed explanations and interpretation of his original presentation at Columbia University. You can also go to my website at www.science-site.net where you will find various web pages of information on this subject.

Lastly, I have proven that Einstein's theory has a fatal flaw. It was based on electromagnetic radiation being spherical, which is NOT the case! I discovered this by simply plotting the waves of radiation from a dipole antenna. This information was known as far back as 1936 when Einstein was still alive. Why hadn't no one, including Einstein, thought to do this simple exercise?